# Save Machine Learning Model progress for later

Tags: machine-learning, train, weights

How do you save the progress an ML model has made and start from that point later? Its kind of a vague question, but this is an example of what I am talking about:

Say, hypothetically speaking, if I just trained a really, really good machine learning model, like 99% testing and training accuracy. The problem is it took me 8 hours to get to that point and I would like the model to START from that point without having to retrain it when I am using it for the future, how would I save that progress?

I am currently messing around with TensorFlow and would like to know how to save progress for a NN I've been training with it.

Comment: depends on the software

Comment: And on the procedure: the answer for a random forest would be different from that for a neural network. (I think asking how to store progress so far when using a particular approach would be on topic here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkpoints are the solution, every deep learning frameworks has this option, keras, tensorflow or pytorch.